# I am getting an Oracle Database Error ORA-20004: Error is Raised in xxxxxxxxxxORA-06512: If the value for clientcode is null

Tags: oracle, plsql

If the value of clientcode in NULL on this stored procedure I am getting  errors please help.

Oracle database error:

> ORA-20004: Error is Raised in xxxxxxxxxxORA-06512:

```
PROCEDURE sp_getclientcontacts (

                                idnumber        VARCHAR2,
                                curreturn   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

IS
    clientcode   VARCHAR2 (50);

BEGIN
    SELECT client_key
      INTO clientcode
      FROM (  SELECT client.client_key
                FROM client
               WHERE client.cli_id_no = idnumber
           )
/*ADVICE(21): This item has not been declared, or it refers to a label [131] */
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1;   
     IF clientcode is not null
     then
        BEGIN
            OPEN curreturn FOR
                SELECT cc.cli_id_no, cc.cli_cell_phone, cc.cli_email
                  FROM insight.client cc
                 WHERE cc.client_key = clientcode;
        END;
        end if; 
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
/*ADVICE(35): A WHEN OTHERS clause is used in the exception section
                  without any other specific handlers [201] */
    THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        raise_application_error (-20004,

                                 'Error is Raised in sp_getclientcontacts');
        NULL;

END;
```

Comment: you should add `CREATE [OR REPLACE]` just before the `PROCEDURE` keyword.

Comment: The stored precedure is aready created but when I call it from  C# i get the error

Comment: "clientcode is null" suggests that you have a `no_data_found` exception that should be handled, due to the first SELECT statement.

Comment: The posted function is throwing the error -20004 (as it should), but since that makes a user written error, the calling routine is failing to handle. That's generates the ora-06512.